Are Protestants the only group that considered themselves really sinful, or is there some other group that also considers human nature the same way?
When Luther broke from Catholic traditions and (according to Protestants) returned to early Catholic faith and to the teaching of the gospel in the New Testament, a lot of attention was paid on the main difference, that being justification by faith alone. It is right to identify this as the main split, however a second order split seems to go largely unnoticed, which is a different view of sin altogether.  Luther thought Christians sin every day, every hour, or rather, every second with ‘mortal sins’, as opposed to ‘venial’ or minor sins.
Note: Catholics differentiate types of sins into multiple categories, something that Luther also rejected entirely.
It seems most Protestants have little interest in understanding the Catholic views, so the difference over the concept of sin is unsurprisingly easier to find documented by Catholics. Even though it is written as an apologetic to the Roman Catholic view, here is a fairly good summary on the different view as described by Catholics.
The basic difference is regarding the desires of our flesh:

Catholic view:

From the explanation given, it is plain that the opposition between appetite and reason is natural in man, and that, though it be an imperfection, it is not a corruption of human nature.


Protestant View:

Concupiscence is of itself sinful, and being the sinful corruption of human nature caused by Adam's transgression and inherited by all his descendants, is the very essence of original sin



In other words those basic desires that we face every day, in the form of temptations, or in the form of preventing us from perfectly loving God, are not necessarily sins according to Roman Catholic teaching but are essential sins according to Protestant teaching. This Protestant teaching is considered heresy by official Catholic doctrine.  In other words, Luther described himself as being way too sinful than what can be accepted by the leaders of the Catholic church, which Luther rejected as being even more sinful than he.
Luther says many places in his writings that ‘all our righteousness are as filthy rags’ and all sin is damnable, otherwise it is not a  sin, so that even in our good works we sin. Or simply put:

No one is able to love God from his whole heart, etc., and his
neighbor as himself [Mark 12:30–31]. We therefore say that a man is
justified by faith, not by love. (Luther’s Works Vol 34, Page 309)

So, my question is: Is this view of sin unique to Protestants, or are there some other large groups taking the name Christian that also see themselves as committing damnable sins, every day (or in less shocking language ‘to be imperfect’ due to the ‘remaining sinful desires of the flesh’), that they need not fear damnation from, due to their justification apart from their own works? Or is it only the Protestants who have this radical view of sin?
Note: This is by no means saying Luther says we can sin willingly and claim to have faith, he means in our imperfect state due to the flesh, we do sin perpetually unwillingly as we make a most admirable attempt to resist sin and love God because our flesh is essentially sinful, which Catholics deny.

To provide some detail on the background history overt his split between the Catholic Church and Luther and provide some additional historic references. Some modern protestants may not even be aware of fundamental difference.

It actually stems from the 95 Thesis by Martin Luther that eventually resulted on this point in condemnation from the Council of Trent, Canon XXV

CANON XXV.-If any one saith, that, in every good work, the just sins
venially at least, or-which is more intolerable still-mortally, and
consequently deserves eternal punishments; and that for this cause
only he is not damned, that God does not impute those works unto
damnation; let him be anathema.

A man named Latomus condemned Luther in response to his thesis and Luther subsequently defended his view.
In response to Latomus Luther defended his view that even in good works Christians sin. It goes without saying that sin, according to Luther was always damnable if not covered by the imputation of Christ’s righteousness by faith.

If the works of righteous men are sins, as Thesis 7 of this
disputation states, this is much more the case concerning the works of
those who are not righteous.

and

The works of God (we speak of those which he does through man) are
thus not merits, as though they were sinless. In Eccles. 7[:20], we
read, “Surely there is not a righteous man on earth who does good and
never sins.” In this connection, however, some people say that the
righteous man indeed sins, but not when he does good. They may be
refuted in the following manner: “If that is what this verse wants to
say, why waste so many words?” or does the Holy Spirit like to indulge
in loquacious and foolish babble? For this meaning would then be
adequately expressed by the following: “There is not a righteous man
on earth who does not sin.” Why does he add “Who does good,” as if
another person were righteous who did evil? For no one except a
righteous man does good. Where, however, he speaks of sins outside the
realm of good works he speaks thus [Prov. 24:16], “The righteous man
falls seven times a day.” Here he does not say, “A righteous man falls
seven times a day when he does good.” This is a comparison. If someone
cuts with a rusty and rough hatchet, even though the worker is a good
craftsman, the hatchet leaves bad, jagged, and ugly gashes. So it is
when God works through us. (Luther’s Works Vol 31,  Page 44)

and

The first article attacked by Latomus is this: Every good work is
sin. First, he deduces unacceptable consequences from this thesis;
second, he opposes it with contrary [views]; third, he impugns my
premises. In driving this Sennacherib [2 Kings 19:28; cf. Isa. 37:29]
back to his own land, I shall begin with the last point and thus start
by defending my own position. In order to deprive me of that wonderful
verse in Isa. 64[:6] which reads, “We have all become like one who is
unclean, and all our righteous deeds are like filthy rags,” he
interprets it so that neither he nor I can use it.
Luthers Works 32, Page 161

Or again Luther describing the sinful nature in complete opposition to a view that imagining obtaining sinless perfection, even if it be for a few minutes in one day:

In this alone we are saved, therefore, that having sin and living in
sin we grieve because we have it and cry to God for deliverance, in
accord with John’s saying (1 John 1:8–9): “If we say we have no sin,
we deceive ourselves, and the truth is not in us. If we confess our
sins, He is faithful and just and will forgive our sins and cleanse us
from all unrighteousness.” In this way, yes, in this way, “The
sacrifice acceptable to God is a broken spirit; a broken and a
contrite heart, O God, Thou wilt not despise” (Ps. 51:17). “For there
is no man who does not sin,” says Solomon in his prayer (1 Kings
8:46). And Moses in Ex. 34:7 says: “Before whom no man of himself is
innocent.” And again, Eccl. 7:20 says: “There is not a righteous man
on the earth who does good and never sins.” And again, “Who can say,
‘I have made my heart clean?’ ” (Prov. 20:9). Therefore: “There is
none righteous. All have turned aside” (Ps. 14:3; Rom. 3:10, 12). Thus
we pray: “Forgive us our debts” (Matt. 6:12). And where do these sins
and debts come from? Because no one fulfills the Law except Christ.
For no living man is justified before God, because his heart is always
weak toward the good and prone toward evil. He does not love
righteousness without in some way also loving iniquity. But Christ
“loves righteousness and hates wickedness” (Ps. 45:7). As the apostle
explains later on in chapter 7:25, “With the flesh we serve the law of
sin, but with the spirit the Law of God.” And thus we are partly
righteous, but not wholly so. Thus we have sin and debt. When we pray,
therefore, that our righteousness be made perfect in us and that our
sin be taken away, we are praying at the same time to finish this
life. For in this life this inclination toward evil will never be
perfectly cleansed, just as the Children of Israel, to use a figure of
speech, could not drive out the Jebusites. Hence, immediately after
the petition “Hallowed be Thy name” (which takes place through our
sanctification from sins and evil works) comes the petition “Thy
kingdom come” (Matt. 6:10), as if he were saying that it will not be a
complete sanctification except in Thy kingdom. But this also will not
come except through tribulations. Therefore the words “Thy will be
done” follow, just as Christ prayed in the garden in the time of His
tribulation. (Luther Works 25, page 246)


"see themselves as committing damnable sins, every day, that they need not fear damnation from, due to their justification apart from their own works?" — How is this different from those that believe in once-saved-always-saved?

The concept of Christians committing 'damnable sins' 'every day' and that 'they need not fear damnation due to justification' is antinomianism and is not Protestant doctrine. No source is quoted for this, above. It is expressed as an opinion. The true doctrine is as stated by the apostle Paul where no law is there is no transgression.

This is rather a conflict between Augustine and overall later Catholic theology, since Luther /reformers has direct roots in Augustine.

@Michael16 - Yes I would agree with that. My question is there anybody else besides Protestants ,that side with Augustine? I have a feeling all the sects are more or less  later Catholic in their view. But I am not sure.

It turns out, upon more research, that the answer to the question is easy. Those that have a traditional Protestant view like Luther, (Arminians excluded), who believe that the urges of the flesh are sin and not fully removed in baptism (thus not just ‘weaknesses’) nor fully removed by some spiritual holiness movement (Arminian), are simply those who do not believe in Christian Perfectionism (see Wikipedia entry).
Those who believe in Christian Perfectionism think, in opposition to Luther, that we can obtain a state of being ‘without sin’, even if that be for only a few years, weeks, or days.  This is the essential idea that Luther argued against and which St. Augustine also denied, by saying that even in our good deeds there is some ‘remnant of sin’ mixed in.  So theoretically even the very righteous and the most holy sin perpetually, by being perpetually imperfect until such time that we are in heaven and made perfect.
Note: This does not mean sin rules over the believer; in fact Luther taught that a believer could never be ruled by the remnants of sin, only that in our righteous living according to the moral laws revealed in scripture and made clear through the Ten Commandments, some sin will always remain in our good works. For example, we never love God in absolute perfection because of the perpetual indwelling sin.
The Wiki article cited above, though not exactly accurate with respect to the Missionary Alliance or the Keswisk churches! (who do not believe in Perfectionism as claimed!) gives a good enough summary of those who reject this doctrine of Perfectionism and therefore also have a similar view to Luther and the Reformers on the underlying nature of sin leading to their rejecting Perfectionism.
Answer: Lutheran and Reformed churches and possibly Christian Science (I have not verified that one from the Wiki article) are those that consider the urges of the flesh to be sinful and not just weaknesses, as post-Augustinian Catholics do, or not completely destroyable in this life, as Arminians do.
In other words, the dispute between Luther and the Catholic church during the Reformation splits the views on the nature of sin. These fundamental differences in turn is the basis for believing or denying Perfectionism.  It is the same topic with the same answer.
The question was perhaps too deep in the woods to convey the simplicity of the topic. It is not really debatable but basic church history.

I think you point your finger to the right distinction.  May I add that Catholics give the name "concupiscence" (which is NOT merely sexual!!) to identify the corrupting element of a good deed when they define the view of sin that Luther rejected, and believe that concupiscence can be overcome by grace with the cooperation of believers, thus holding one of the variants of Christian Perfectionism (see this Wikipedia article section).

@GratefulDisciple - Excellent link to bring clarity to a complex topic. Thanks.

After giving some examples of Luther's views on sin, you ask "Is this view of sin unique to Protestants..."? No. It is unique to the Bible, but unfortunately many of Luther's biblical expositions are either taken out of context or misunderstood.
Few people seem aware of the view of sin Luther had been brought up with in the Catholic system, and which reached its tortured culmination when he was a monk. When we compare that with what he said about sin after his conversion to Christ, much should be corrected. Luther became an Augustinian monk and this is how one biography describes that time:

"He fasted, sometimes three days on end without a crumb... Lent was
more comforting than Easter. He laid upon himself vigils and prayers
in excess of those stipulated by the rule. He cast off the blankets
permitted him and well-nigh froze himself to death. At times he was
proud of his sanctity and would say, 'I have done nothing wrong
today.' Then misgivings would arise. 'Have you fasted enough? Are you
poor enough?' He would then strip himself of all save that which
decency required. He believed in later lie that his austerities had
done permanent damage to his digestion.
"I was a very good monk, and I kept the rule of my order so strictly
that I might say that if ever a monk got to heaven by his monkery it
was I. All my brothers who knew me in the monastery will bear me out.
If I’d kept on any longer I should have killed myself with vigils,
prayers reading and other work."
But he eventually had to admit that such methods gave no sense of
inner tranquillity. The purpose of his striving was to compensate for
his sins but he could never feel that the ledger was balanced. So,
comfort was found in the Catholic idea of pooled goodness (merit).
Monks were told of the corporate view of goodness, and some saints
were so much better than they needed to be for their own salvation,
their superfluous merits formed a treasury to those whose accounts are
in arrears (spiritually speaking). Here I Stand - Martin Luther,
Roland Bainton pp.45-46, Lion, 1987 ed.

Luther was transferred from Erfurt to Wittenberg and lived in the Augustinian cloister. There was a university there. The Elector, Frederick the Wise, invited some Augustinians and Franciscans to come as professors. One was Luther, in 1511. The vicar of the Augustinian order was Johan von Staupitz, who became Luther's confessor. Luther said, "If it had not been for Dr. Staupitz, I should have sunk in hell." But Dr. Staupitz almost sank under the deluge of Luther's confessions of sins! Luther's assiduous confessing allegedly got Staupitz exclaiming in exasperation:

"Look here, if you expect Christ to forgive you, come in with
something to forgive - parracide, blasphemy, adultery - instead of all
these peccadilloes."
But Luther's question was not whether his sins were big or little, but
whether they had been confessed. The great difficulty which he
encountered was to be sure that everything had been recalled. He
learned from experience the cleverness of memory in protecting the
ego, and he was frightened when after six hours of confessing he
could still go out and think of something else which had eluded his
most conscientious scrutiny." (Ibid. pp. 54-55 bold emphasis
mine)

This was all before Luther nailed those theses of his to the door. This was what Catholicism had ingrained into him, from infancy. He had a dread of hell, and was desperate to have the Catholic church deal with his sins in the prescribed way so that he would escape hell. Being a monk was one of the best ways, he and many others thought. Yet his most zealous endeavors to be a good monk gave him no peace with God. No amount of confessing could, either; not even hour after hour of confessing. This means that Catholic teaching about people being really sinful and needing to confess to priests was already a massive force in the lives of the populace. Even if they thought lightly of sin, they knew they still had to confess sin for all their worth to stand any chance of escaping hell. Yet that teaching is not biblical, as Luther went on to discover, for it is not any church that can deal with our sin, if we confess it all to its priests. As the book adds:

"There is according to Luther, something much more drastically wrong
with man than any particular list of offenses which can be enumerated,
confessed, and forgiven. The very nature of man is corrupt. The
penitential system fails because it is directed to particular lapses.
Luther came to perceive that the entire man is in need of
forgiveness." (Ibid. p. 55)

Luther had to be liberated by grace from wrong doctrine about sin. That happened once he studied the Bible, especially Romans. Then he discovered that Christ had done it all, for no sinful human can do enough, despite obedience to religious systems. It is only faith in what the Son of God did that lifts the burden of our sins. Compare Luther's views of people being really sinful, as a Catholic, with his views of human nature being corrupted by sin, as a Bible-believing, repentant follower of Jesus.
Another point that must not be skipped is that the idea that Christians can sin almost ad infinitum yet be assured they are still forgiven, is the heresy of Antinomianism. Luther can never be charged with that heresy! But his words can be distorted. This is where going back to the previous point in this answer (about the Catholic view of sin he had, which he had to be liberated from by the gospel of grace) is essential.
Be assured that Catholics have always had a view of the depth and magnitude of human sin. Where Protestantism differs is in the way God deals with the forgiveness of that sin, and after they have discovered God's forgiveness, they abhor sin far more, knowing what it cost God to deal with it, once and for all. But they also know the chains of sin enslaving them have been smashed by Christ; fear of condemnation is gone, but desire to please God through appreciative obedience replaces that.
EDIT due to this addition to the question: "Luther means in our imperfect state due to the flesh, we do sin perpetually unwillingly as we make a most admirable attempt to resist sin and love God because our flesh is essentially sinful, which Catholics deny."
If only this had been included at the start, my answer would have taken a different tack. Suffice to say that Luther took the biblical doctrine of sin quite differently after he'd studied the book of Romans, to how he took the Catholic doctrine of sin prior to his conversion. Yes, Catholicism taught the grave seriousness of sin, and so does (or should) Protestantism. But it is the theological application of how Christians are to view sin after God has freely forgiven them that is the point of divergence.
Both groups should stress how "really sinful" we all are. No difference there. One group, however, denies the sinful nature of fallen humanity that we are born into and cannot escape, claiming water sprinkling gives the 'new birth' with membership into their church. Even new babies can experience this. Not so Luther and Protestantism.
It is only by individuals being convicted by the Holy Spirit of their utterly sinful standing before God that they can truly repent through hearing the gospel, truly be born from above of the Spirit, and truly become part of the ecclesia, the church Christ said he would build, which the gates of Hades could never overcome.
Only after such miracles of grace can a sinner discover the joy of forgiveness; that he is no longer a slave bound to sin, turning his back on sin to follow Christ, and Christ alone - not a denomination or a religious system that says "Do this, do that, and certainly don't do the other, and you should be okay with God."
Luther found the true, biblical doctrine of sin in the Bible, the Holy Spirit brought him to spiritual life, and he was then "free in Christ" (but not free to sin, quite the opposite, fleeing sin as never before.) He escaped a system that held out eventual forgiveness, like a carrot dangling before him, with the stick of purgatory and hell-fire behind him. The quote I gave at the start shows how that affected him. But the biblical doctrine of sin and how God in Christ did everything necessary to deal with sin in righteousness liberated him to holiness of living, free from a system of bondage to rituals, superstition and fear.

Up-voted +1, for a gallant effort to bring order out of chaos.
